# ¿Para que sirve el "<meta name='viewport>' "?

Tags: html

Lo he visto mucho en HTML pero no se con exactitud para que sirva, ayuda por favor

Comment: ayuda a renderizar las paginas para que sea multi propósito, osea lo que haces es adaptar la pagina a la pantalla de tu móvil,tablet o pc. se usa mucho para los diseños responsives y ayuda en el SEO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es una etiqueta HTML5 y sirve para optimizar los sitios para móviles, esta etiqueta ayuda a definir el ancho, alto y escala del área usada por el navegador para mostrar contenido. Su uso básico es de la siguiente manera:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Como información adicional, te comparto un video en donde explica mucho más:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OP2GnAFeFTY

Comment: muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 4):

Es para configurar el espacio que utilizara tu sitio web, como te han mencionado es así:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

la parte que dice:

```
width=device-width
```

define el ancho del sitio web en este caso el ancho es el ancho del dispositivo. Las otras dos que dicen:

```
initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1
```

sirven para definir la escala del sitio web, ¿Te haz dado cuenta que puedes hacer zoom? a esto se refiere con la escala al definir una escala inicial y una maxima iguales te aseguras de que no se pueda hacer zoom, esto es util en sitios web móviles ya que el zoom en estos generalmente estropean la visibilidad del sitio.

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2):

Si mal no recuerdo sirve para controlar la composición para teléfonos moviles, que nos ayuda en la presentación de nuestros proyectos web en telefonos moviles

Comment: muchas gracias!!